# TypeScript version warning, TypeScript xx feature Current language level is xx, in visual studio 2019

Tags: typescript, visual-studio

My VS 2019 installed Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild 4.2.3 as shown below.

Win 10 OS aslo installed it via NPM like below:

However, in VS 2019, the warnning below is shown

> TypeScript 3.4 feature Current language level is 3.1

[image]

```
tsc --version
Version 4.2.3
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2019?view=vs-2019

Comment: What does your project's `package.json` look like? It should have a "typescript" dependency or devDependency. (For context: in general, TS projects use a local dependency, not a globally installed tsc or an editor tsc. You _can_ use something global, but it just create more problems than it solves).

Comment: I don't have `package.json`, but `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild 4.2.3` nuget is used, as shown on the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Likely as mentioned is picking up a locally installed node package version that is overriding the installed VS version for this project.

Look in your NPM package.json, and update the version to latest, and then do a NPM install and try again

Comment: `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild 4.2.3` nuget is already used in VS 2019, which is local. as shown in the screenshot in OP.

Comment: Not Nuget. Node package. NPM

Comment: NPM is also already installed, as shown in OP `tsc --version
Version 4.2.3`

Comment: Right. Which likely has a Typescript version installed